# What is the best possible way to pass data between child components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am curious to know if the performance of a React app will be affected if we have multiple nested components and we pass a callback function to the lowest-level component and then the entire component tree is rendered from an event in the lowest-level component that triggers this callback.

If so, what are the best possible ways to tackle this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are plenty of ways to pass data, but less so for functions.

Redux could be used, or useContext, or some other external solution like [jotai](https://jotai.org).

Actually, the recommended official way is useContext: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-avoid-passing-callbacks-down

```
const TodosDispatch = React.createContext(null);

function TodosApp() {
  // Note: `dispatch` won't change between re-renders
  const [todos, dispatch] = useReducer(todosReducer);

  return (
    <TodosDispatch.Provider value={dispatch}>
      <DeepTree todos={todos} />
    </TodosDispatch.Provider>
  );
}

function DeepChild(props) {
  // If we want to perform an action, we can get dispatch from context.
  const dispatch = useContext(TodosDispatch);

  function handleClick() {
    dispatch({ type: 'add', text: 'hello' });
  }

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Add todo</button>
  );
}
```

But frankly, passing a function several components down isn't so bad either.

It makes data dependencies more explicit and improves testability, although it's a bit verbose indeed. Do what you feel is more right. You can change your approach later (in this case) pretty easily.

Comment: If you ever went the useContext route, you can have a look at this https://jotai.org/

Comment: Thanks Igor, and in terms of performance do you think one is better than the other?

Comment: The proposed @DheerajSharma solution should the best in performance so far. useContext was never too performant, and I think it'll lose in this race.